# php- changing text box's to already known values

Tags: php

hey guys I have a chunk of code here that takes three values and creates sub domains based off of the entries.  i was wondering how i could take the idea of this form and modify it.  specifically what i am trying to do is put in php variables where the text entry box's are.  can any expert reply and tell me how this could be done?

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo network_admin_url('site-new.php?action=add-site'); ?>">
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'add-blog', '_wpnonce_add-blog' ) ?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr class="form-field form-required">
            <th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Site Address' ) ?></th>
            <td>
            <?php if ( is_subdomain_install() ) { ?>
                <input name="blog[domain]" type="text" class="regular-text" title="<?php _e( 'Domain' ) ?>"/>.<?php echo preg_replace( '|^www\.|', '', $current_site->domain );?>
            <?php } else {
                echo $current_site->domain . $current_site->path ?><input name="blog[domain]" class="regular-text" type="text" title="<?php _e( 'Domain' ) ?>"/>
            <?php }
            echo '<p>' . __( 'Only the characters a-z and 0-9 recommended.' ) . '</p>';
            ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="form-field form-required">
            <th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Site Title' ) ?></th>
            <td><input name="blog[title]" type="text" class="regular-text" title="<?php _e( 'Title' ) ?>"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="form-field form-required">
            <th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Admin Email' ) ?></th>
            <td><input name="blog[email]" type="text" class="regular-text" title="<?php _e( 'Email' ) ?>"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="form-field">
            <td colspan="2"><?php _e( 'A new user will be created if the above email address is not in the database.' ) ?><br /><?php _e( 'The username and password will be mailed to this email address.' ) ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php submit_button( __('Add Site'), 'primary', 'add-site' ); ?>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply..  i have data stored in a database, and i have them pulled out and stored as php variables.  every time new data comes into the database, i want it to go through the actions of this script.  does this make it clearer?

Comment: What do you mean by 'go through the actions of this script'? If you want data from your database appear in broswer as default (changeable) value in your input boxes - use solution **Senad Meškin** provided. If you want this data to appear in browser as static, unchangeable text - use mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="blog[email]" type="text" class="regular-text" title="<?php _e( 'Email' ) ?>" value="<?php _e($array['Email']);?>"/>
```

$array['Email'] is variable where you hold data that should be prefiled or it can be $email

Comment: I believe [`_e()` is Wordpress i10n function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e), so it shouldn't be used for email address (or any other user data).

Comment: thanks for the reply..  i have data stored in a database, and i have them pulled out and stored as php variables.  every time new data comes into the database, i want it to go through the actions of this script.  does this make it clearer?

Comment: _e() is also as I can remember method which will return translated version of 'Email' if exists otherwise it will return provided text. yes this is custom method not php method, but you  can also use echo $Email, just find a way to put data from db into variable.

Comment: @Senad Meškin I meant that `_e()` can translate common static strings (like: `Email` -> `Почта`), but is useless (and probably dangerous) applied to user data (like email address: `address@domain.com`- which cannot be translated obviously).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you want, but you can output static string instead of input box like this:

instead of:

```
<input name="blog[email]" type="text" class="regular-text" title="<?php _e( 'Email' ) ?>"/>
```

use

```
//usual syntax
<?php echo $blog['email']; ?>
//short syntax
<?= $blog['email'] ?>
```

or use **Senad Meškin**' solution to set default value to your input box.

Comment: thanks for the reply..  i have data stored in a database, and i have them pulled out and stored as php variables.  every time new data comes into the database, i want it to go through the actions of this script.  does this make it clearer?